# Show that $ x_{n+1}=\dfrac{4+3x_n}{3+2x_n} $is an increasing sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence defined by $x_1=1$ and $ x_{n+1}=\dfrac{4+3x_n}{3+2x_n} \text{for} \hspace{0.2 cm }n=1,2,3...$

Show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence

First I used to prove $x_{n}\leq x_{n+1}$ by using mathematical induction but it is not success then I used a function

$f(x)=\dfrac{4+3x}{3+2x} $ which first derivative is always positive thus I conclude that $f(x)$ is an increasing function thus $x_{n}\leq x_{n+1}$

Can anyone help me I don't know what I am doing is correct or not?

If anyone help me to prove this using mathematical induction it is better!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction hint:

$$
2 x_{n+1} = \dfrac{8+6x_n}{3+2x_n} = 3 - \dfrac{1}{3 + 2 x_n} \implies 2(x_{n+1} - x_n) = \dfrac{2(x_n - x_{n-1})}{(3+2x_n)(3+2x_{n-1})}
$$

The denominator is positive, so the difference between consecutive terms keeps the same sign.

Answer (score 3):

You have differentiated the function and shown that it is positive, you can also check that $x_1<x_2$ manually. Then you have from the mean value theorem

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{4+3x_n}{3+2x_n}-\frac{4+3x_{n-1}}{3+2x_{n-1}}=f'(c)\cdot(x_n-x_{n-1})>0, c \in (x_{n-1},x_n)$$

where we used the induction hypothesis $x_n>x_{n-1}$ and the fact that the derivative is bigger than zero.

**Only induction:**

First use induction to show that $x_n$ is positive, this is very easy.

Then we get:

Check first manually that $x_1<x_2$. Assume now that $x_{n-1}<x_n$ we get

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{4+3x_n}{3+2x_n}-\frac{4+3x_{n-1}}{3+2x_{n-1}}\\=\frac{(4+3x_n)(3+2x_{n-1})-(4+3x_{n-1})(3+2x_n)}{(3+2x_n)(3+2x_{n-1})}\\=\frac{12+8x_{n-1}+9x_n+6x_nx_{n-1}-12-8x_n-9x_{n-1}-6x_nx_{n-1}}{(3+2x_n)(3+2x_{n-1})}\\=\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{(3+2x_n)(3+2x_{n-1})}>0,$$

where we have used the induction hypothesis, $x_n>x_{n-1}$ and the fact that $x_n,x_{n-1}$ is positive.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to prove to only using mathematical induction

Comment: @noname I think it is, but I can't see it right now, I'll try and let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: @noname I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Without induction*:

As all terms in this sequence are positive, we have
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{3x_n+4}{2x_n+3}>x_n\iff (2x_n+3)x_n<3x_n+4\iff 2x_n^2<4\iff x_n<2$$

Now rewrite the  recurrence relation:
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{3x_n+4}{2x_n+3}=\frac32+\frac1{2(2x_n+3)}<\frac32+\frac 12=2.$$

Comment: There is typo in first line

Comment: @noname: Yes. Thank you for pointing it! I should definitely reread more  carefully what I wrote before posting…

Comment: @Bernard "*all terms in this sequence are positive*" Technically, that follows by induction ;-) That's just being overly pedantic, of course (+1).

Comment: @dxiv: To be frank, I don't think induction is really necessary to see that (or maybe, as one of my teachers used to say, ‘a nursery school induction’…) ;o)